# CodeIgniter - Consulta em banco de dados PostgreSQL (multi database)

Tags: codeigniter, mvc, framework

Bom, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que faz uma listagem. A listagem é produzida mediante a consulta de um banco de dados. A listagem x é gerada somente pela consulta no banco x, a listagem y, gerada somente pela consulta no banco y, etc. Nem um resultado deve se cruzar, a exemplo, retornar a listagem de X e Y na mesma página.

Até o presente momento, eu consegui retornar a consulta no banco MySQL, utilizando as classes do CI para banco de dados. Porém, um dos bancos que devo fazer a consulta é o PostgreSQL.

No banco do PostgreSQL, existe algumas schema, o que seria divisões para formar outros "bancos".

A minha dúvida reside aí, como faço para colocar o `SET search_path TO blablabla` no CI.

OBS¹: as consultas com os bancos MySQL estão retornando os devidos resultados, o problema só se encontra para definir o `search_path`.

OBS²: Sei que é possivel realizar o procedimento por meio do `$query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY')`, porém, gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar o Active records.

OBS³: Não tentei realizar `query()` ainda para realizar a consulta, mas creio que não encontraria problemas em retornar o resultado por meio dela, só queria aproveitar os outros métodos que usei para o MySQL.

**Aqui está minha model atualmente**

```
class Crud_model extends CI_Model {

    public $banco_mysql;
    public $banco_postgre1;
    public $banco_postgre2;
    public $banco_postgre3;

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->banco_mysql = $this->load->database('bd_01', TRUE);
        $this->banco_postgre1 = $this->load->database('bd_02', TRUE);
        $this->banco_postgre2 = $this->load->database('bd_03', TRUE);
        $this->banco_postgre3 = $this->load->database('bd_04', TRUE);
    }

    public function get_name($row) {

        $this->$row['bd']->from($row['path'] . '.' . $row['tabela']);
        $this->$row['bd']->like($row['coluna'], strtoupper($row['name']));

        $result = $this->$row['bd']->get();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Os dados contidos no `$row['bd']` vem de um array, nele é contido o nome do banco que eu quero carregar. Se eu deixar dessa forma no construtor, ele irá funcionar, pelo menos no MySQL.

```
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->banco_mysql = $this->load->database('bd_01', TRUE);
    }
```

Comment: Só uma coisa, nem tudo é possível com o Active Record, algumas coisa irá ter que usar o `$this->db->query('sua query')` ou até `$this->db->simple_query('sua query')`

Comment: Disso eu tenho noção, mas o que me interessa, é "padronizar" as conexões, ou o máximo de coisas possíveis.

Comment: Mas vc ja consegue fazer uma consulta simples nos dois bancos em uma unica pagina, mysql e postgres? ou essa que eh a sua duvida?

Comment: Então, na verdade, eu notei que não consigo fazer a consulta nos dois bancos. Parece que, ao instanciar um banco, o outro não instância. Se eu instanciar os dois bancos, nem um deles funciona, simplesmente aparece uma página em branco. Aí tenho que pesquisar uma forma de instanciar um deles e no final da consulta, finalizar essa instância para que a outra seja feita. Mas até agora, não fui atrás de uma solução, se vc tiver uma forma, e puder me ajudar, vou deixar a forma atual que meu model editando o post inicial.

Comment: Entao, seu problema deve ser esse de nao estar conseguindo instanciar mais de um banco de dados ao mesmo tempo, e nao esse outro ponto que vc colocou, se conseguir usar os dois bancos ao mesmo tempo ja deve resolver isso. Da uma olhada nesse link que deve te ajudar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634291/codeigniter-using-multiple-databases

Answer (score 1):

Bom, procurando algumas coisas relacionadas ao CI e PostgreSQL, achei um cara com uma dúvida semelhante e resolvi tentar algo semelhante ao que ele fez.

Para quem tiver interesse, e talvez o mesmo problema, solucionei o problema da seguinte forma:

```
class Crud extends CI_Model {

    public function consulta($var) {

        $this->db->select('title, content, date');
        $this->db->from('search_path.mytable');
        $this->db->like('nome_coluna', $var['nome']);

        $result = $this->db->get();
     }
}
```

Só basta colocar o nome da schema, ou banco, na linha que especifica qual a tabela a ser procurada (no caso: `$this->db->from('search_path.mytable');`).

Dessa forma, é possível inserir o `search_path` do PostgreSQL e de outros bancos de dados que utlizam o mesmo sistema.